# Связь языков PHP, C#, Python

Tags: php, c#, sql, python, веб-программирование

Есть три человека. Один занялся HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, SQL. Второй - Python, SQL, C#. Третий - C#, SQL, слегка налёг на Web и планирует на Java перескочить. Как это всё можно связать для совместной работы? В каких, скажем, областях. Как можно одновременно задействовать ресурсы троих человек в данных сферах? Что можно сделать общее? И если можно, более подробно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотите начать свой проект?
Можно, например, делать какой-нибудь веб проект, с различными приложениями под *Android*, *iOS*, *PC* и *Web-интерфейсом*.

В принципе, можно делать почти любой проект, который вы будете продавать. Думаю, что сделать конкретно, никто вам не подскажет. Если бы у меня была отличная идея, что именно сделать, то я бы уже делал.

А вообще, если у вас возникают такие вопросы, по принципу, что бы замутить, и нет идеи, в которую вы верите, то устройтесь на работу каждый по своему направлению. Скорее всего, так вы заработаете больше, чем поднимая свое дело, и не рассоритесь в пух и прах.